# WITH statement for structures

Tags: abap

In some languages there exist syntax to simplify method and property access of a single object. As an example from VB.NET:

```
With foo
   .bar()
   .reset(true)
   myVar = .getName()
End With
```

Or as Jagger points out, in [Pascal](http://pascal-programming.info/lesson11.php#2):

```
With myBookRec do
 Begin
  Title  := 'Some Book';
  Author := 'Victor John Saliba';
  ISBN   := '0-12-345678-9';
  Price  := 25.5;
 End;
```

Now I often find myself setting a ton of properties on a given structure. Take for instance the classic case of setting a field catalog:

```
LOOP AT lt_fieldcat INTO ls_fieldcat.
    CASE ls_fieldcat-fieldname.
        WHEN 'COLUMN_1'.
            ls_fieldcat-edit = ''.
        WHEN 'COLUMN_2'.                
            ls_fieldcat-edit = 'X'.     
            ls_fieldcat-outputlen = 20.
        WHEN 'COLUMN_3'. 
            ls_fieldcat-edit        = abap_true.
            ls_fieldcat-drdn_hndl   = '2'.
            ls_fieldcat-drdn_alias  = 'X'.
            ls_fieldcat-outputlen   = 5.
            ls_fieldcat-col_pos     = 1.
            ls_fieldcat-scrtext_s   = text-f01.
            ls_fieldcat-scrtext_m   = text-f01.
            ls_fieldcat-scrtext_l   = text-f01.
    ENDCASE.
    MODIFY lt_fieldcat FROM ls_fieldcat.
ENDLOOP.
```

Is there any way to replicate WITH-like functionality in ABAP?

If not, is there a better way to replicate this behaviour?

---

I've actually considered replicating the "return this" method daisy chain for a field catalog class. This seems like a WITH-alternative but I'm not entirely sold on its usefulness, given that you'd have to maintain a class for every structure.

```
ls_fieldcat = zcl_fieldcat=>new( ls_fieldcat )->edit('')->outputlen(20)->col_post(1)->get().
```

Comment: I'd use `LOOP AT ... ASSIGNING` for this to get rid of the `MODIFY` operation and the data transfer...

Comment: @vwegert: Agreed. It's just a sample I created from a legacy program though. :)

Comment: Interesting thing that such a keyword was already available in [Pascal](http://pascal-programming.info/lesson11.php#2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the new ABAP syntax you could simplify your code a bit with `VALUE #( ... )` statement (or `VALUE #( BASE ls_fieldcat ...)` for modifying a structure with already assigned fields) which can be used for emulating `WITH` in ABAP. Not a perfect solution, especially if one has a `CASE` structure like yours but surely neat for initalizing a structured variable.

```
LOOP AT lt_fieldcat INTO ls_fieldcat.
    CASE ls_fieldcat-fieldname.
        WHEN 'COLUMN_1'.
            ls_fieldcat = VALUE #(
              BASE ls_fieldcat
              edit = ''
            ).
        WHEN 'COLUMN_2'.
            ls_fieldcat = VALUE #(
              BASE ls_fieldcat
              edit = 'X'
              outputlen = 20
            ).
        WHEN 'COLUMN_3'.
            ls_fieldcat = VALUE #(
              BASE ls_fieldcat
              edit        = abap_true
              drdn_hndl   = '2'
              drdn_alias  = 'X'
              outputlen   = 5
              col_pos     = 1
              scrtext_s   = text-f01
              scrtext_m   = text-f01
              scrtext_l   = text-f01
            ).
    ENDCASE.
    MODIFY lt_fieldcat FROM ls_fieldcat.
ENDLOOP.
```

Comment: Excellent suggestion. I hadn't considered how the `VALUE` operator could be used to streamline this particular scenario and I wasn't actually aware of the `BASE` addition. You can go even crazier and use the `SWITCH` operator to avoid typing the result structure more than once, though at that point I think you're trading readability for brevity. Example: `ls_fieldcat = SWITCH #( ls_fieldcat-fieldname WHEN 'COLUMN_1' THEN VALUE #( BASE ls_fieldcat edit = '' ) WHEN 'COLUMN_2' THEN VALUE #( ... ) [...] [ELSE ...] ).`

Answer (score 2):

I don't think the daisy-chain approach is that useful - it's not much easier to read, and if anything goes wrong, it's awfully hard to debug. Personally, I'd probably use a "multi-setter" with multiple optional attributes:

```
  lr_my_field->set_attributes( edit  = abap_true
                               title = 'foo'
*                              ...
                               bar = 'baz' ).
```

That being said, I don't have a problem with the code in your question at all. Clearly readable, simple data handling. Just put it away into a method named `PREPARE_FIELDCATALOG` and everone knows what to expect.

Comment: Good point, I hadn't considered the debugging angle. Daisy-chaining is probably only worthwhile for methods with actual logic behind them and then such calls might indeed confuse other developers. I'm not too fussed about the current code but since I knew of alternatives existing in other languages I wanted to check that I wasn't missing an obscure ABAP feature.

Comment: Funny thing, because there is something tolling at the back of my head, that such an obscure feature existed. Let me dig into some old book on ABAP and I'll get back to you.

Comment: @Jagger: There's the colon notation for `MOVE: a TO b, c TO d, e TO f.`, but that won't help in this case. It'll only make you appear 60 years older than you are...